# -confirm not working

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to run

```
Set-SPManagedAccount -Identity $SPUser -ExistingPassword $nPassword -Confirm
```

But it is asking me to confirm again. I tried couple of other method by changing `$confirmpreference`, but it didn't help. I am not sure why it is asking for confirmation. How do I stop it asking for confirmation?

Answer (score 2):

You need to explicitly set the value of `Confirm` to `$false` to avoid being prompted:

```
Set-SPManagedAccount -Identity $SPUser -ExistingPassword $nPassword -Confirm:$false
```